# UDF not working in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark, shark-sql

I'm trying to calculate Jaccard index on Spark SQL. My table on `Hive` has the following data:

```
hive> select * from test_1;

1   ["rock","pop"]
2   ["metal","rock"]
```

**Table DDL:**

```
create table test_1
(id int, val array<string>);
```

I'm using the `UDF` from [Brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/sketch/SetSimilarityUDF.java). From `spark-shell`, I'm able to execute the following commands to create the temporary function.

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.hql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION jaccard_similarity AS 'brickhouse.udf.sketch.SetSimilarityUDF'")
```

I have also added the `.jar` file to the `CLASSPATH` for `spark-shell` (in `compute-classpath.sh`).

When I list the functions, I'm able to see the new function that I have created.

```
hiveContext.hql("show functions").collect().foreach(println)
```

Next, I use the `jaccard_similarity` function to calculate the Jaccard Index for the `val` array.

```
hiveContext.hql("select jaccard_similarity(a.val, b.val) from test_1 a join test_1 b")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select jaccard_similarity(a.val, b.val) from test_1 a join test_1 b
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO Analyzer: Max iterations (2) reached for batch MultiInstanceRelations
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO Analyzer: Max iterations (2) reached for batch CaseInsensitiveAttributeReferences
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=test_1
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO audit: ugi=username  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=test_1   
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=test_1
14/07/31 15:39:56 INFO audit: ugi=username  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=test_1   
scala.MatchError: ArrayType(StringType) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.types.ArrayType)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveInspectors$typeInfoConversions.toTypeInfo(hiveUdfs.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$.lookupFunction(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$transformExpressionDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(HiveContext.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.simpleString(HiveContext.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.toString(SchemaRDDLike.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.toString(SchemaRDD.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.scala$runtime$ScalaRunTime$$inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:324)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:329)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1056)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:645)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:841)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:753)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:611)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:884)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:982)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I looked at the `Spark` source code from GitHub. In [datatypes.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/types/dataTypes.scala), there's the following code:

```
 protected lazy val arrayType: Parser[DataType] =
    "ArrayType" ~> "(" ~> dataType ~ "," ~ boolVal <~ ")" ^^ {
      case tpe ~ _ ~ containsNull => ArrayType(tpe, containsNull)
```

I couldn't find any reference to `array` being not supported by Spark SQL. It would be great if anyone can share any pointers on how to get this working.

Also, the function works perfectly from `Hive` shell.

**Update (5th August):**

I just build Spark from the Master branch on Github. The error message has some more info (like `scala.MatchError: ArrayType(StringType,false)` instead of `scala.MatchError: ArrayType(StringType)`)

```
scala> hiveContext.hql("select jaccard_similarity(a.val, b.val) from test_1 a join test_1 b")
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select jaccard_similarity(a.val, b.val) from test_1 a join test_1 b
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=test_1
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO audit: ugi=chandrv1  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=test_1   
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=test_1
14/08/05 13:54:53 INFO audit: ugi=chandrv1  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=test_1   
scala.MatchError: ArrayType(StringType,false) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.types.ArrayType)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveInspectors$typeInfoConversions.toTypeInfo(HiveInspectors.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(hiveUdfs.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideFunctionRegistry$$super$lookupFunction(HiveContext.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:41)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$class.lookupFunction(FunctionRegistry.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.lookupFunction(HiveContext.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$transformExpressionDown$1(QueryPlan.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsDown(QueryPlan.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$.apply(Analyzer.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(HiveContext.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.simpleString(HiveContext.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.toString(SchemaRDDLike.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.toString(SchemaRDD.scala:103)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.scala$runtime$ScalaRunTime$$inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:324)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:329)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1061)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:645)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I also looked at [HiveInspectors.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveInspectors.scala) (line 212, `typeInfoConversions`). It seems that `ArrayType` isn't defined there.

Comment: Does this function return one number? Or an array?

Comment: @Ashalynd It returns a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, my reputation on StackOverflow is not high enough to leave a comment. Hope this "answer" reaches you well. Anyway, I'm playing on SparkSQL using HiveContext and noticed quite a similar behaviour with ArrayType. Although it does not solve your problem, it might explain why

It turns out that ArrayType are supported on HiveContext (Spark 1.1.0) **only** when using spark "internal" tables structure. Whenever you try to access spark "external" hive tables (i.e. hosted on metastore), you might face similar issues with ArrayType not supported..

Here is a simple illustration

```
// ************
// ArrayType is supported when playing with SparkSQL temp tables...
// ************

val sqlContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val rdd = sqlContext.jsonFile("/tmp/test.json")
rdd.printSchema
/*
    root
    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- names: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
*/

sqlContext.registerRDDAsTable(rdd,"test")
val out = sqlContext.sql("SELECT names FROM test")

// ************
// ...But fail on Hive statements
// ************

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT names FROM test")

/*
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 16, vagrant): scala.MatchError: ArrayType(StringType,true) (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.types.ArrayType)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.cast$lzycompute(Cast.scala:247)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.cast(Cast.scala:247)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.eval(Cast.scala:263)
.../...
*/
```

I still don't know exactly why / where it fails, but HiveContext does not (fully) support ArrayType. **Anyway, I doubt the issue you're describing here is related to your jaccard UDF function..**

Alternatively, uses such a (working) ugly hack :)

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE mytable AS SELECT split(concat_ws('#',names),'#') FROM test")
```